# add authorization header in MultipartRequest in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) in dart in order to upload files to API. However I need to add an authorization header to my request. The problem that i am facing is that the header attribute is final and I can't overwrite it. How can I fix that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`headers` is a `Map`, so add the key/value.

```
http.MultipartRequest request =
    new http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.headers['authorization'] = 'the auth header value';
```

Comment: The documentation for [`MultipartRequest`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) lists the `headers` property as "final, inherited", does final not mean what I think it means?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to pass all the preconfigured header (key, value) Map, from your, let's say `_headers`, you can do something like:

```
_headers.forEach((k, v) {
  request.headers[k] = v;
});
```